# Numpy polyfit - covariance matrix

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

When fitting a straight line to a set of data, weighted with errors, I was expecting polyfit to return a 2x2 covariance matrix from which I could square root the diagonal elements to find the uncertainty in the coefficients, but I don't.

Here's a minimum working example:

```
from numpy import polyfit

x=[1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.]
y=[1.,3.,2.,4.,5.,6.,6.,8.,9.]

yerr=[10.,5.,3.,2.,10.,10.,10.,10.,10.]

linear = polyfit(x,y, 1, w=yerr, full=True)

print(linear)
```

With output:

```
(array([ 0.95730623,  0.11546722]), array([ 114.79556527]), 2, array([ 1.38182992,  0.30090875]), 1.9984014443252818e-15)
```

Thanks!

Comment: try set the arguments: `cov=True`, `full=False`.

Comment: @HYRY you could post your comments as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [document](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) says:

- cov : bool, optional

  Return the estimate and the covariance matrix of the estimate If full is True, then cov is not returned.

So set `cov=True` and `full=False`(default setting) will return the convariance matrix.